# Ruby or Rails native Feed parser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

```
require 'rss'
RSS::Parser.parse('http://www.ecoreboxing.com/feed/')
```

Is that all we get that's native?  Is [feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) still the defacto gem for parsing feeds? Any [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) fans out there?  Seems that [hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) accepted defeat to nokogiri?

I've tried installing feedzirra... it worked for a while, but I keep getting curl / curb errors.  meh.  I'd like something a bit more... well, native.  Can `URI` do anything with this?  I feel like this is too simple of a task to not be... easier?

Comment: I've always just used Nokogiri. It's dead simple and is extremely robust.

Comment: do you use the XML command or the html command?  have a small sample I could see?